# koush/ion getting json in in textview

Tags: java, android, json, android-ion

I'm trying to understand Koushi-ion's code so that i can get json data from website and input it into a listview. for now i am testing it with just a textview.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.testview);
        test = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.testview1);

        Ion.with(getApplication(), "mywebsite")
        .asJsonObject()
        .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
           @Override
            public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
                // do stuff with the result or error
               inputTest = result.getAsString();
               test.setText(inputTest);
            }
```

i get the logcat error `:unsupportedoperationException: JsonObject at com.google.Gson.JsonElement.getAsString(JsonElement java:191);`

Is it not that simple with Ion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using Gson incorrectly. just use result.toString if you want the json as a string.

Comment: Just gives null pointer exception. Im really just shooting in the dark here cuz i have no idea how to use this Library for anything other than images. How do i parse data to a textview with this? theres absolutely no documentation whatsoever on this.

Comment: You likely have an exception then. Check the exception value "e".

There's plenty of javadoc and examples as well: https://github.com/koush/ion#get-json

If you have questions on how to use Gson, that's a Gson question, not Ion.

Comment: @crushman , if you got the answer on **how to set json into a textview**, please share it with am having the same problem

Comment: @koush , please you too help me out am new in using **ion**, you can check out my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39996356/setting-json-data-to-a-textview-using-ion-library